# How can scala see classes from files in command line mode?

Tags: scala, command-line

Say, I have an eclipse project located in `D:\DanHenderson\scala\MyProject`. MyProject has 2 directories: `src` and `bin`. In `src` I have scala code itself, it might be some classes or an application. So how can I use those classes or run whole application from command line? I.e., there is a file with class `A`, and I want to have a possibility to type `val a = new A` in command line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By command line I assume you mean the Scala REPL. Add the directory of your class files to the classpath when starting the Scala REPL:

```
scala -classpath "path to some dir where your .class files reside"
```

Note that if your project relies on some libraries then those need to be on the classpath as well.

Comment: My solution was to cd to bin directory and that's it -- all classes are visible in windows cmd.

Comment: @Zapadlo Yeah, that works as well since the working dir is included on the classpath.